# Electric Dipole Moment

Tags: electrostatics

Electric dipole moment = $q\cdot d$, where $q$ is the magnitude of the charges and $d$ is the distance between them.

So, if the distance between them increases, the dipole moment increases but I read that the electric field strength of the dipole is proportional to the magnitude of dipole moment. How is the electric field strength increasing with increasing distance , shouldn't it be decreasing?

Comment: The "distance" being increased is the distance between the charges. And the "distance" that that you refer to in the next sentence is the distance from the "center" of the dipole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @Anonymous_original is correct.

Consider the electric field at some distance $y$ perpendicular to the mid point between the two equal but opposite charges of the dipole separated by a distance $d$. The electric field at $y$ is the vector sum of the individual field contributions of the two charges.

Now consider what happens to that field when the distance $d$ between the charges decreases. In the extreme case, if the two charges were brought to the same point their electric fields would cancel out completely since the charges are equal and opposite, leaving no field at $y$. If they have a small distance separating them, they will produce a feeble electric field at distances $y$ from them.

Hope this helps.